# BlackJack CARDSET WITH 52 Cards

Tags: c#

I have a question: **I want to create a BlackJack CardSet with 52 Cards BUT** when I **fill the cards with my Method --> it is 104**. I have  **4x CardSuits** and **13xCardValue**. 4x13 should be 52 but its always 104 (twice 52)

```
List<Card> cardset = new List<Card>();

public CardSet()
{
    AddCardsToSet();
}

public Card CreateCard(CardValue cardValue, CardSuit cardSuit)
{

    return new Card(cardValue, cardSuit);
}

public void AddCardsToSet()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
        {
            cardset.Add(new Card((CardValue)j, (CardSuit)i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you're calling `AddCardsToSet` twice, for example, once more after the constructor is done?

Comment: Looks like `AddCardsToSet` should be `private`

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hi, thank you that was the problem ) I really didnt see it....

Comment: Thanks everbody for helping, I figured it out now. :)